# SQL query - how to construct a multirow dependent where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have table like this:

```
**********************************
* row * field *  item  * content *
**********************************
*  1  *  231  *   10   *    A    *
*  2  *  232  *   10   *    C    *
*  3  *  231  *   11   *    A    *
*  4  *  232  *   11   *    B    *
**********************************
```

I would like to SELECT DISTINCT only the item for which there are both: field=231 & content=A  AND  field=232 & content=B (item for which exists both those rows with those values). So, in this case result should be 11.

If I put WHERE clause like this:

```
where (field=231 and content=A) OR (field=232 and content=B)
```

the result will be both 10 and 11 because first row comply with the condition inside the first parenthesis. If I put 'AND' instead of 'OR' than I get nothing back because WHERE clause is tested only at one row and there is no row that meets such condition.

How to construct the WHERE clause that gives back only the item 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `item` and take only those having your conditions

```
select item
from your_table
group by item
having sum(case when field=231 and content='A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when field=232 and content='B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in Access and it seems there is no 'case when' so I had to change it a little: having sum(IIf(field=231 and content='A',1,0)) > 0 and sum(IIf(field=232 and content='B',1,0)) > 0

Answer (score 1):

I think the most general way to approach this type of problem is with `group by` and `having`:

```
select item
from table t
group by item
having sum(case when field=231 and content=A then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when field=232 and content=B then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause checks that exactly one condition is true.  The `> 0` says that at least one row matches.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in Access and it seems there is no 'case when' so I had to change it a little: having sum(IIf(field=231 and content='A',1,0)) > 0 and sum(IIf(field=232 and content='B',1,0)) > 0

Comment: I accept it because I forgot to mention Access so when you read the question and then see the answer - it is correct. Your answer is also correct but unfortunately I can accept only one answer here - I have tried to accept all answers but it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match conditions in two different rows, you need to join the table with itself

```
select t1.item
from table t1
join table t2 ON t1.item=t2.item
where t1.content='A' AND t1.field=231
   and t2.content='B' and t2.field=232
```